# spring OAuth2 service to service client credentials

Tags: microservices, spring-security-oauth2

I have a set of services behind a zuul gateway, one of which is the auth server. I have it configured to parse the jwt with a jwk set from the auth server at `/.well-known/jwks.json` for users on each service with a password grant to access simple endpoints, but i'm wondering if it's possible to decide on a case by case basis which controllers and endpoints are using the user's access token vs using the service's client credentials when those services have to call other services. for example:
I have a contact service that manages customers, and another service that manages inventory.
When a user wants to see which customers are interacting with which inventory, i'm able to use an `OAuth2RestTemplate` to call the other service like so

```java
@RequestMapping("/sales/{id}")
public Map<Object, Customer> getSales(@PathVariable Long customerId) {
  Object inventory = restTemplate.getForObject("http://inventory-service/inventory", Object.class);
  Customer customer = repository.findById(customerId);

  Map<Object, Customer> sales = new HashMap;
  sales.put(customer, inventory);
  return sales;
}
```

I'm getting a 500 response `A redirect is required to get the users approval` even though i've tried configuring the Customer service to use client credentials flow instead of authorization code flow.

the security settings for the customer service:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      jwk:
        key-set-uri: ${GATEWAY:http://localhost:8762}/.well-known/jwks.json
    client:
      client-id: first-client
      client-secret: noonewilleverguess
      access-token-uri: ${GATEWAY:http://localhost:8762}/oauth/token
```

with the main class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`, `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)`, and `@EnableResourceServer`.

here's some more configuration for context

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
  }

  @LoadBalanced
  @Bean
  public OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate(OAuth2ClientContext clientContext,
                                         OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resourceDetails) {
      return new OAuth2RestTemplate(resourceDetails, clientContext);
  }
```

the documentation suggests that `@EnableOAuth2Client` isn't necessary when exposing the `OAuth2RestTemplate` so i have omitted that annotation.

Ideally i'd like to be able to pick and choose which requests use the user's access token and which requests use the service's client credentials, but i haven't found any resources that do so. Is it even possible?